# What is a good openid selector control?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth, rpxnow

Now that [idselector](http://www.idselector.com/) has been upgraded to [RPXNow](http://rpxnow.com/) and you can't "just use" the selector code, what is a good replacement?

I want to implement OpenId on a new website that I am using, but the users are going to be just dumb when it comes to logging in unless I provide an easy way for them to.

As a reference, I will be using .Net Open Id for the background in an ASP.Net MVC web application.

---

**EDIT**

After some cheap thought, what about using the [rpxlib](http://code.google.com/p/rpxlib/)?

Comment: I really dislike RpxNow.  It doesn't really simplify much as you now have a proprietary protocol to talk to an unnecessary intermediary between your site and the openid Provider.  Also, the trust_root/realm is rpxnow.com, which means you're hooked to them forever, or you splinter Google accounts.

Comment: what do you mean on splintering?

Comment: For those considering RpxNow but have concerns about what "trusted root" url is shown on a providers login page, RpxNow does have pro accounts that allow you to have your own trusted root url, and, even at $1K or so can be more than worth it if one doesnt want to maintain direct interface code with so many providers and their versioning (OpenId, Facebook, LiveID, MySpace).

http://rpxwiki.com/Realms-and-Trust-Roots

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[**Jarrett Vance**](https://web.archive.org/web/20190911021133/http://jvance.com:80/pages/JQueryOpenIDPlugin.xhtml)  made a "version" of open-selector that is much more developer/designer friendly.

> This selector is different because **it does not hide the markup details in javascript**.  Therefore, **you can easily add new providers** or rearrange the existing ones without digging into the javascript.  The login form will still work for normal OpenID logins if javascript is disabled

The best of all, is that it comes with documentation, demo, and lots of images both cropped and as raw [.pdn](https://www.getpaint.net/index.html) files ([paint.net](https://www.getpaint.net/index.html))

Jarrett Vance's [openid-selector](https://web.archive.org/web/20190911021133/http://jvance.com:80/pages/JQueryOpenIDPlugin.xhtml) [can be found here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190911021133/http://jvance.com:80/pages/JQueryOpenIDPlugin.xhtml)

[image]
<sub>(source: [jvance.com](http://jvance.com/media/2009/02/10/JQueryOpenIdPluginUser_thumb2.media))</sub>

**PS: I would suggest reading [this article](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2009/01/why-using-rpxnow-is-bad-idea.html) before implementing RPX.**

Comment: I've followed all the links in the above post but can't find a download link

Comment: There's nothing downloadable here either: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/OpenId

Answer (score 8):

Another one to consider is http://code.google.com/p/openid-realselector/ (which is a rewrite/update of http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/)

Comment: As of today, there is nothing to download on the download page of openid-realselector.

Comment: @nthpixel: The same in 2013.

Answer (score 4):

I have done an implementation with RPXLib and RPXNow, and it is really pretty straight forward.

I wanted to minimize the amount of work done in the OpenId format, and the RxpLib definately helped with that one.

RpxNow also has a nice feature of telling me new users, number of logins per day, etc...

Answer (score 4):

I've made [Open-selector](http://open-selector.com), which you just add to your site and switches the regular OpenID box into a provider list and a username text input.

The code is pretty simple (in case you need extra customization) and there is an inline mode so it doesn't alter your original layout.

Answer (score 3):

I was using that one, but then I found a few people using a different one which made me investigate, and I found this [OpenID selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/). There aren't any instructions per se other than the demo.html, but it shouldn't be too hard to figure out. Just include the css and js, then call the javascript function with the right parameter.

Edit about rpx: I chose to stay away from rpx because I didn't want to have a 'central point of failure,' and a site that isn't my own that users would authenticate to/through. It seems kind of counter-intuitive being that I'm using openid, but if you consider that the openid provider that the user is using as part of the user, then it kind of makes sense.

Comment: I can't say that i care for that one, other then the fact that it shows the images and does a get submission to your page, I would prefer one that had a bit more interactivity (like the idselector one pre-populating the urls)

Comment: I just implemented that one and found 2 obvious bugs right away :( We'll see if the maintainers show some love for it.

Comment: The code has been forked since my comment. It fixed a couple things I noticed with it: http://code.google.com/p/openid-realselector/