# Integrating OpenID into a website's registration process

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, openid

I want to integrate the same registration process that Stack Overflow has into my website. Does anyone know if this is possible and any ways I can go about doing this?

I am using ASP.NET MVC for my site implementation. It would be awesome if someone could point me in the right direction with some examples etc.

Comment: @close-voter(s) : I don't think that this belongs on meta : the question is not about SO, but about integrating something like OpenId (used on SO) on another website -- so, looks programming-related to me.

Comment: Agree, don't close - just using SO as an example. (Unfortunately I did before the edit to make the title clearer).

Comment: My mistake, I misunderstood and voted to close: don't! it's valid

Comment: But stackoverflow uses google accounts and yahoo and AOL accounts etc. as well....I want to know how to implement for each of these as well as OpenID.

Comment: google etc accounts are openID accounts. And that is how stackoverflow is using them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's also [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net:8000/).

**Edit:**

[Andrew Arnott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46926/andrew-arnott) also pointed out in the comments that there is a pretty awesome [OpenID selector control](http://jvance.com/pages/JQueryOpenIDPlugin.xhtml) available. The Stack Overflow question it relates to is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418790/what-is-a-good-openid-selector-control).

**Thanks Andrew!**

Comment: And you can combine it with an OpenID Selector control (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418790/what-is-a-good-openid-selector-control) to get the UI you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

You can find out how to use OpenID [here](http://openid.net/add-openid/add-getting-started/).